# how can i set the pin image to the one that i downloaded in alamofireimage

Tags: dictionary, firebase, swift3, marker, alamofireimage

im trying to change the marker or pin image to the one i download from firebase with alamofireimage. Please i need help

this is my code:

```
let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: milatitud!, longitude: milongitud!)


        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        annotation.coordinate = coordinates
        annotation.title = "JuanJo"
        self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)

        //print ("4444444444")


        for annotation: MKAnnotation in self.map.annotations {

            let anView = self.map.view(for: annotation)

            if (anView != nil)


            {
                let url = URL(string: link!)
                self.imagen.af_setImage(withURL: url!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "usuarioprevia.jpeg"), filter: CircleFilter(), imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.5), runImageTransitionIfCached: true, completion: nil)

                anView?.image = "image downloaded from firebase with alamofireimage"









            }
```

i dont know the last part how to set it = for displaying the image, also i need to resize it. Please help

Comment: You are not showing the code that is responsible for downloading the image from firebase, can you please post that?

Comment: Yes im showing it, it is the part "self.imagen.af_setimage..." i have the photos in a url so alamo fire image is downloading it from an array that contains url